# IllegalArgumentException when trying to bind Remote object to RMI registry

Tags: java, rmi, illegalargumentexception

I've written a simple RMI application, but I cannot bind my Remote object to the RMI registry.
The RMI registry is running from a separate cmd window [I'm on Windows 10].
The Remote interface is very simple:

```
package matram;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface RemoteInterface extends Remote {
    public String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

The implementation is also simple:

```
package matram;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class Test1 extends java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject implements RemoteInterface {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Test1() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHello() throws RemoteException {
        { return "Hello world!"; }
    }
}
```

Here's the server, which contains the main method:

```
package matram;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.rmi.Naming;

public class RemoteDCmain {

    public static Test1 dc;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) { System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager()); }

        try {
            String name = "DCregistry";
            dc = new Test1();
            Naming.rebind(name, dc);
            print("dc bound");
        }
        catch (java.rmi.RemoteException ex) {
            print("Remote Exception");
            ex.printStackTrace();;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            print("Naming.rebind exception:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            final InetAddress localaddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            print("Local IP Address : " + localaddr);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            print("Can't detect localhost : " + e);
        }

        init();

    } // main

    private static void init() {
        try {
        //  (new Thread((Runnable) dc)).start();
            Thread.sleep(1200);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            print(String.format("Could not connect to account W"));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // init()

    public static void print(Object o) {
        System.out.println("DC server: " + o);
    }
}
```

When I run it [from within Eclipse], I get

```
DC server: Naming.rebind exception:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

    at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.addPermissionsForURLs(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.getLoaderAccessControlContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.lookupLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at matram.RemoteDCmain.main(RemoteDCmain.java:16)
```

I'm really at a loss re where this is coming from. And I haven't even invoked the client yet...

Comment: You didnt declare the remote registry: LocateRegistry.createRegistry( Registry.REGISTRY_PORT );

Comment: @Supahupe Yes he did. The Registry is running. The Registry threw the exception. See the stack trace. If it wasn't running he would have got a `ConnectException`, not this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
```

You are using a `file:` URL somewhere.

```
  at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.lookupLoader(Unknown Source)
```

You are using a class loader.

Conclusion: you are specifying an invalid `file:` URL in the `java.rmi.serve.codebase` system property.

I would also ask you why you're using a `file:` URL at all. It won't be any use to the client unless the client is on the same host, in which case you don't actually need the codebase feature at all.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that I [unfortunately] have a space in my file URL: rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:"///C:/Users/Shahar/Box%%20Sync/git/MATraM/target/classes/matram/" (that's the directory with the .class files) - is there a more appropriate way to substitute a space?

Comment: `%20` is correct for an HTTP URL, but `%%20` isn't correct for any URL. Assuming that is a typo and you really had just `%20`, I would try a literal space.

Comment: **%20** gives a java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**: matram.RemoteInterface
**Literal space** gives java.rmi.ServerException : RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: **java.net.MalformedURLException : no protocol**: Sync/git/MATraM/target/classes/matram/

Comment: Regarding the last part of your answer, I am not sure I understand the alternative to using a `file:` url or forgoing the codebase feature altogether. When I run `rmiregistry` without the codebase argument, I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: matram.RemoteInterface`

Comment: You can either use the `-J-classpath` argument; run the Registry from the directory named; or start the Registry from inside then server JVM, with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`.

Comment: Or use an `http:` URL, which will be useful to the client as well.

Comment: I had to move my whole Eclipse project to a folder that does not have a space character in its path. Now it seems to be working [with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`].

Comment: You shouldn't have been using the Eclipse folder as the codebase in the first place, as it won't be there at runtime, and now that you're using `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` you don't need the codebase feature at all.

Answer (score -1):

One thing to remember for a better practice of integrated components in Java is the use of CMD. I'm not discouraging you for the use of eclipse but RMI is a different case. Here in Java RMI you need to start RMI registry on some free port (say 4545) explicitly by using the Command `rmiregistry 4545`, Also you need to compile the Server Class not with `javac` but with `rmic`. One last thing; use a fully qualified url for rmi server address. Ex : `rmic://localhost:4545/myServer`

Comment: This is not correct. You can start rmi-service from within a jvm => LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4545);

Comment: And you do need to compile the server with `javac`. The `rmic` process comes after that, and it has been optional for 13 years. You have failed to observe that the server *is* not only compiled but executing, to the point of being able to supply its own stub. And none of this has anything to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: There are various ways...I have mentioned what I use and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: That's not true. What you actually said was that you need to start the RMI Registry '*by using the command ...*', and it is that which continues to be incorrect.